# HTML - CSS not being applied to id

Tags: php, html, css

I'm newbie and trying to make a E-commerce website using Xampp. I'm unable to get the items in content area in a ordered way (see images). **What I want** [image: is something like this] **but I am getting** [image: content area like this].
The code for content area in index.php is:

```
         <!--content area in pink color-->
               <div id="content_area">
                  <div id="products_box">   
                   <?php getPro(); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

getPro() function in functions.php is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
//get the products
function getPro () {
    
     global $con;
     
     $get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";
     $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
     while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
         
         $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
         $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
         $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
         $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
         $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
         $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
         
         echo "
             <div id='single_product'>
             
             <h3>$pro_title</h3>
             <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />
             <p><b>₹ $pro_price</b></p>
             
             </div>
         ";
     }
}
```

CSS code in style.css is:

```
#products_box { 
    width:780px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#single_product{
    float:left; 
    margin-left:20px; 
    padding:10px;
}
```

generated HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
   
        <title>My online shop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" media="all" />   
   
   </head>
  
<body>
   <!--Main Container starts here-->
   <div class="main_wrapper">
         <!--header starts here-->
         <div class="header_wrapper">
            
              <img id="logo" src="images/logo.gif" />
              <img id="banner" src="images/ad_banner.gif" />
              
         </div>
         <!--header ends here-->
         
         <!--Navigation bar starts here-->
         <div class="menubar">
                <ul id="menu">
                
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                
                </ul>
                <div id="form">
                  <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  
                       <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="search a product" />
                       <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
                       
                   </form>
                </div>
         </div>
         <!--Navigation bar ends here-->
         
         
         <!--Content wrapper starts here-->
         <div class="content_wrapper">
         
             <div id="sidebar">
                    
                    <!--categories-->
                   <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>
                   
                   <ul id="cats"> 
                       
                    <li><a href='#'>Laptops</a></li><li><a href='#'>Cameras</a></li><li><a href='#'>Mobiles</a></li><li><a href='#'>Tablets</a></li><li><a href='#'>media players</a></li><li><a href='#'>Ebook readers</a></li><li><a href='#'>Graphic tablets</a></li>   
                    
                   </ul>
                   
                   <!--Brands-->
                   <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>
                    
                   <ul id="cats"> 
                       <li><a href='#'>HP</a></li><li><a href='#'>DELL</a></li><li><a href='#'>LG</a></li><li><a href='#'>Samsung</a></li><li><a href='#'>Apple</a></li><li><a href='#'>Motorola</a></li><li><a href='#'>Xiamoi</a></li><li><a href='#'>Huawei</a></li><li><a href='#'>Blackberry</a></li><li><a href='#'>HTC</a></li>                 </ul>
             </div>
             
                  <!--content area in pink color-->
                  <div id="content_area">
                      <div id="products_box">   
                       
             <div class='single_product'>
             
             <h3>Moto G5 Plus (Lunar Grey, 32 GB)</h3>
             <img src='admin_area/product_images/motorola-moto-g5-plus-1.jpg' width='180' height='180' />
             <p><b>₹ 15999</b></p>
             
             </div>
         
             <div class='single_product'>
             
             <h3>xiamoi redmi note 3</h3>
             <img src='admin_area/product_images/Redmi-Note3-32GB-SDL881680011-2-1b99d.jpg' width='180' height='180' />
             <p><b>₹ 9999</b></p>
             
             </div>
         
             <div class='single_product'>
             
             <h3>Dell Vostro 15 3558 15.6-inch Laptop</h3>
             <img src='admin_area/product_images/Dell Vostro 15 3558 15.6-inch Laptop.jpg' width='180' height='180' />
             <p><b>₹ 28000</b></p>
             
             </div>
         
             <div class='single_product'>
             
             <h3>Iphone 6 (32 GB)</h3>
             <img src='admin_area/product_images/SP705-iphone_6-mul.png' width='180' height='180' />
             <p><b>₹ 30000</b></p>
             
             </div>
                          </div>
             
             
             
             </div>
         
         </div>
         
         <!--Content wrapper ends here-->
         <div id="footer">
         <h2 style="text-align:center; padding-top:30px;">&copy; 2017 by Technohub
          
         </div>  
   
   </div>
<!--Main Container ends here-->
</body>
</html>
```

*Please explain in detail as I'm a newbie*

Comment: One problem is that you're generating multiple `<div>` elements with the same `id`.  That's not legal HTML5, `id`s must be _unique_ in a document, use a `class` instead,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the same ID multiple times,

**IDs must be unique**,

So use a class instead

instead of `<div id='single_product'>` use something like `<div class='single_product'>`

then in CSS

```
.single_product{
    float:left; 
    margin-left:20px; 
    padding:10px;
}
```

---

### Answer after question edited

- Here is your code improved using `flexbox`

```css
#products_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 780px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  /*demo*/
  background: pink
}

.single_product {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--content area in pink color-->
<div id="content_area">
  <div id="products_box">
    <div class='single_product'>
      <h3>Moto G5 Pluspl (Lunar Grey, 32 GB)</h3>
      <img src='//placehold.it/180' />
      <p><strong>₹ 15999</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class='single_product'>
      <h3>xiamoi redmi note 3</h3>
      <img src='//placehold.it/180' />
      <p><strong>₹ 9999</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class='single_product'>
      <h3>Dell Vostro 15 3558 15.6-inch Laptop</h3>
      <img src='//placehold.it/180' />
      <p><strong>₹ 28000</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class='single_product'>
      <h3>Iphone 6 (32 GB)</h3>
      <img src='//placehold.it/180' />
      <p><strong>₹ 30000</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: giving it a try, give me a minute

Comment: Still getting the same result :<

Comment: sadly its not working too. Im getting the same result. I think problem is with some other part instead of "#product_box" and ".single_product". Can you please give it a last try.

Comment: with the current output, you just need to change the CSS, meaning you don't need to change PHP, PHP is fine, just copy paste the CSS, if that doesnt work, then the problem is you have some other CSS overriding it

Comment: Yes I only changed the CSS last time also. I think you are right, Some other CSS overriding it.

Comment: just to be sure use `!important` in each property, if it works it is a CSS problem, then remove it and try to fix it, if not I don't know what might be

Comment: Nope !important not working either. I'll consult my faculty tomorrow and if i get answer i'll post it here for future reference. thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

**For future reference:**

1. As @dippas stated, IDs must be unique.
2. Now you just need to ***clear cache and cookies*** and it will work.